# Show Preview Vide from react-native-image-crop-picker

Tags: reactjs, react-native, video, react-image-crop

How can I display a **preview image** of a video in components I captured with package "react-native-image-crop-picker"?

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**: The <Image src=yourState.path "component supports displaying the first frame from video MP4.